# Is there a formal title for Larry's "lying inspection" bit?

Tags: terminology, trope, curb-your-enthusiasm

When Larry suspects someone of lying, he inches toward them and "inspects" their face while a song plays. This happens all the time throughout *Curb Your Enthusiasm*.

Is there a name for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would love to fall down the rabbit-hole that is TVTropes, might I suggest you to the trope: [Living Lie Detector](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LivingLieDetector)

> A character with the ability to always know when someone is lying.

The [Curb your Enthusiasm](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Series/CurbYourEnthusiasm) show comes under this trope...

> When Larry suspects someone of lying, he will stare at them suspiciously for several seconds, trying to detect if they're lying or not. The same leitmotif ("The Puzzle") always plays on the soundtrack. The audience is left to draw their own conclusion about how effective his method is.